# how do I reposition a styled label to a corner of its div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How would I move the content inside of .toggle-button to the far right lower corner?

I am new to html and css but from what I understand I've played around with the flex settings, margins, and paddings and I'm not having any luck figuring this out

Here is my code. I am only concerned with the page-header div (color blue border) and the toggle-button div (color purple)

```css
.mypage{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-right: 1vh;
}

.date-dropdown{
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.dates-label {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dates-select {
    margin-left: 1vh;
}
.title-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle-button{
    border: 1px solid purple;
    flex-grow: 1;
}



/* ============= TOGGLE Button  ======= */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #eceeef;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: inherit;
    -moz-transition: inherit;
    -o-transition: inherit;
    transition: inherit;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before {
    content: attr(data-off);
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
    content: attr(data-on);
    left: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #E1B42B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
    left: 74px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 
/* Transition
========================== */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
    transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.switch-yes-no {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after, .switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #32CD32;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    background: #eceeef;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
    display: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 boilerplate – all you really need…</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="home">
<div class="mypage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">

            <div class="date-dropdown">
                <div class="dates-label">
                    <label for="dropdown">
                        Choose a date
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="dates-select">
                    <select name="dropdown" id="datesid">
                        <option>option 1</option>
                        <option>option 2</option>
                        <option>option 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="title-wrapper">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle-button">
                <label class="switch switch-yes-no">
                    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-pie-wrapper">
            <div class="table">
                i am a table
            </div>


            <div class="pie-graph">
                i am a pie graph 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-summary-wrapper">
            <div class="table-summary">
                i am  a table summary
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `margin-left: auto` or in the shorthand that you used:

```css
.switch-yes-no {
  ...
  margin: 15px 0 0 auto;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
.mypage {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-right: 1vh;
}

.date-dropdown {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.dates-label {
  font-size: large;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dates-select {
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.title-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-button {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* ============= TOGGLE Button  ======= */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition
========================== */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.switch-yes-no {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-image: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after,
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #32CD32;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
  background: #eceeef;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
  display: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<div class="mypage">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">

      <div class="date-dropdown">
        <div class="dates-label">
          <label for="dropdown">
            Choose a date
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dates-select">
          <select name="dropdown" id="datesid">
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle-button">
        <label class="switch switch-yes-no">
          <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
          <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
          <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-pie-wrapper">
      <div class="table">
        i am a table
      </div>
      
      <div class="pie-graph">
        i am a pie graph
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-summary-wrapper">
      <div class="table-summary">
        i am a table summary
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If you want the whole button to be in the right bottom corner you can use `align-self: flex-end`:

```css
.toggle-button {
  ...
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
.mypage {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-right: 1vh;
}

.date-dropdown {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.dates-label {
  font-size: large;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dates-select {
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.title-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-button {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}


/* ============= TOGGLE Button  ======= */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition
========================== */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.switch-yes-no {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-image: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after,
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #32CD32;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
  background: #eceeef;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
  display: none;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<div class="mypage">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">

      <div class="date-dropdown">
        <div class="dates-label">
          <label for="dropdown">
            Choose a date
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dates-select">
          <select name="dropdown" id="datesid">
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle-button">
        <label class="switch switch-yes-no">
          <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
          <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
          <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-pie-wrapper">
      <div class="table">
        i am a table
      </div>
      
      <div class="pie-graph">
        i am a pie graph
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-summary-wrapper">
      <div class="table-summary">
        i am a table summary
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I have no reputation so I can't upvote but hopefully someone else who see's this can.

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I addded following css rules `toggle-button` class

```
display: flex;
justify-content: end;
```

Please check the following code snippet

```css
.mypage{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-right: 1vh;
}

.date-dropdown{
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.dates-label {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dates-select {
    margin-left: 1vh;
}
.title-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle-button{
    border: 1px solid purple;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}



/* ============= TOGGLE Button  ======= */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #eceeef;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-sizing:content-box;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: red;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: inherit;
    -moz-transition: inherit;
    -o-transition: inherit;
    transition: inherit;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before {
    content: attr(data-off);
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
    content: attr(data-on);
    left: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #E1B42B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
    left: 74px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 
/* Transition
========================== */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
    transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.switch-yes-no {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after, .switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #32CD32;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    background: #eceeef;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
    display: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 boilerplate – all you really need…</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="home">
<div class="mypage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">

            <div class="date-dropdown">
                <div class="dates-label">
                    <label for="dropdown">
                        Choose a date
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="dates-select">
                    <select name="dropdown" id="datesid">
                        <option>option 1</option>
                        <option>option 2</option>
                        <option>option 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="title-wrapper">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle-button">
                <label class="switch switch-yes-no">
                    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-pie-wrapper">
            <div class="table">
                i am a table
            </div>


            <div class="pie-graph">
                i am a pie graph 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-summary-wrapper">
            <div class="table-summary">
                i am  a table summary
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```